# Как запретить изменять размер ячеек CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

Во время пользования CKEditor обнаружил что размер ячейки таблицы изменяется в зависимости от количества содержимого. Как это исправить?
https://jsfiddle.net/uds0uauc/

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<body>
  <textarea name="editor1">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </textarea>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Неужели это невозможно?

Comment: редактируй скрипт ckeditor. Внутри <textarea name="editor1"> размер не работает https://jsfiddle.net/n5h9vpk0/ но если editor1 удалить то заработает https://jsfiddle.net/ejdt61nj/